# Log into Mongodb with Spring

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, logging

**Update**

I have added an example project in [github](https://github.com/p595285902/spring-boot-web-jsp) to troubleshoot the issue, I have a feeling this is not an issue about the properties nor the dependencies. Must be some basic setup stuff that I missed.

**Original**

I am not able to have a single log into my mongodb with Spring.
Any suggestion will be appreciated!

I would also like to understand the meaning of `applicationId` property. As [spring-data-mongodb](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/tree/master/spring-data-mongodb-log4j) doesnt show much detail.

Here is my `log4j.properties` file(**UPDATED**):

```
#log4j.rootCategory=ALL
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.springframework.data.mongodb.log4j.MongoLog4jAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p [%c] - <%m>%n
log4j.appender.stdout.host = localhost
log4j.appender.stdout.port = 27017
log4j.appender.stdout.database = logs
log4j.appender.stdout.collectionPattern = %c
log4j.appender.stdout.applicationId = my.application
log4j.appender.stdout.warnOrHigherWriteConcern = FSYNC_SAFE

log4j.category.org.apache.activemq=ERROR
log4j.category.org.springframework.batch=DEBUG
log4j.category.org.springframework.data.document.mongodb=DEBUG
log4j.category.org.springframework.transaction=INFO

logging.level.org.springframework.data.document.mongodb=DEBUG
```

Here is my mongo and logging dependencies:

versions are 1.10.3.RELEASE

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb-log4j</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

mongodb version :`db version v3.4.4`

Comment: Is that the entire log file ? Did you define root logger config ? Something like `log4j.rootCategory=INFO, stdout`

Comment: Yes thats everything in the log4j.properties file. The answer you suggested doesnt work.

Comment: Hi, I download your project and run it. And guess what, it puts log into mongodb :)

Comment: I knew it! must be a setup thing that I missed. Do you remember what parts are modified? And what did you do on mongodb side?

Comment: `logging.level.org.org.springframework.data=DEBUG`
You need to put this in `application.properties`

Comment: Hi @Will, I chanced nothing in your shared project. Everything seems fine with the exclusion. For my mongodb part, it is a local mongodb instance with no security(no password needed) May be your mongodb connection needs password and username? In that case you need to add credientials to your log4j.properties(not sure about that part).

Comment: Hi @barbakini, interesting, I dont have any security on my local either. Tried the exclusion  but failed again.I dont know what could be wrong now. Here are my steps :1. run mongod 
2. run mongo 
3. run SpringBootWebApplication.Java 
4. open browser with url localhost:8080 
5. run `show dbs` in mongo shell 
and from here I dont see the database logs, I have also tried to create a database with a dummy collection

Comment: Hi @Will, I can't say anything exactly but your problem is more likely a permission issue with mongodb or your local system. As I said earlier your shared project log into mongodb.

Comment: @barbakini Mongodb is working fine, I have being using it as my application database. That's why I was wondering if there is anything 'simple' and overlooked.

Comment: I am able to insert logs into mongodb by following [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=miqtbm7x60A), is the a xml configuration available that does the same thing with properties?

Comment: I am giving both of you credits for being there to help! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which logging framework you are using, but basically you need to add appender by adding maven dependency to your project if you are using LOG4J

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb-log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I do have this in pom file, it is 1.10.3.RELEASE from the spring parent pom. And have `spring-data-mongodb` as well.

Comment: The logs are printed in my console, I havent used any other appenders.

Comment: Please list you logging dependecies

Comment: try 
`logging.level.org.springframework.data.document.mongodb=DEBUG`
or
`log4j.category.org.springframework.data.document.mongodb=DEBUG`


if above does not work try
`Logger log = Logger.getLogger( "org.mongodb.driver" );
 log.setLevel(Level.DEBUG);`

Comment: Do you have `log4j.rootCategory=DEBUG, stdout` in your `log4j.properties`

Comment: This is required as well `log4j.category.org.springframework.data.mongodb=DEBUG`

Comment: I have tried the above suggestions, but didnt work out for me. Note: I was using sl4j Logger then I switched to apache lo4j.Logger; but still doesnt work.

Comment: Please try adding this dependency `slf4j-log4j12`

Comment: No luck with `slf4j-log4j12`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147419/discussion-between-will-and-fg78nc).

Comment: You need to put 
`logging.level.org.springframework.data.document.mongodb=DEBU‌​G` in application.properties

Answer (score 1):

This works for me. I think you need to exclude spring boots default logging.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

And for log4j property file:

```
log4j.rootCategory=WARN, stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.springframework.data.mongodb.log4j.MongoLog4jAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p [%c] - <%m>%n
log4j.appender.stdout.host = localhost 
log4j.appender.stdout.port = 27017
log4j.appender.stdout.database = logs
log4j.appender.stdout.collectionPattern = %X{year}%X{month}
log4j.appender.stdout.applicationId = some-service
log4j.appender.stdout.warnOrHigherWriteConcern = FSYNC_SAFE
log4j.category.org.apache.activemq=ERROR
log4j.category.org.springframework.batch=DEBUG
log4j.category.org.springframework.data.document.mongodb=DEBUG
log4j.category.org.springframework.transaction=INFO
```

And where I want to log:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(GlobalExceptionHandler.class);
logger.warn("MethodArgumentNotValidException", ex);
```

Comment: I got the following error when exclude
 `org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; 
....
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Logger`. Yours worked might because it wasnt a web application.

Comment: Did you add spring-boot-starter-log4j dependency?   It is like exclusion works but the log4j dependency adding is not.

Comment: Mine was like this
`<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
   <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
  </dependency>`.  The difference here was I am using spring-boot-starter-web instead of spring-boot-starter for a web application.

Comment: I have spring-boot-starter-web in my pom too. Plus the dependency above and making exclusion for that dependency. Can you try in this way?

Comment: nope, I also created a new project and doesnt work as well. I have updated my question with a github project, wondering if there is any setup issue since everything looks legit.

Comment: Hi, I download your project and run it. And guess what, it puts log into mongodb :)